Screen Flow - Display Text Component Visibility Issue
Display Text Component Visibility Issue
In Screen Flow, when you send someone back to a previous screen, the Display Text component visibility is not working because it's not recognizing changes to flow variables/data.
The Debug Details pane in the flow are showing the correct information, but the screen does not match the Debug Details and it's showing past information.
It's much easier to just show the issue, so I uploaded a quick video to YouTube:
https://youtu.be/8dJWy_Y0lmk
I'm assuming this is some kind of browser cacheing issue - I'm using the most recent version of Chrome. Anyone know how to get around this issue?

For your second issue, does your 'ICRM File Uploader' component have any sessionStorage properties to set? I'm not familar with that particular component.
However, a common file uploader our company has used in Flows is Improved File Uploader by Unofficial SF. However you'll see if you scroll to {!$Flow.InterviewGuid} in the below link, that it needs a unique identifier so it doesn't get lost when using ContentDocumentLink records due to flow screens/caching:
https://unofficialsf.com/from-josh-dayment-improved-file-upload-in-flow-screens/#wp-block-heading
